# Google Chrome crashes the whole system on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, google-chrome

`Google Chrome 40.0.2214.111` keeps crashing on my `Dell XPS L502X` with Ubuntu installed on it. How can I remedy this behaviour? The crash affects the whole system in such a way that the mouse cursor is frozen, no keyboard shortcut works, I cannot kill the X-server etc. The only way out is a reset by pushing down the power button for some time. At first this issue was present only when a large number of tabs were open, but now even with 3 or 4 tabs I experience this issue.

This is not present in my other laptop `Dell Latitude E5440` with `Google Chrome 40.0.2214.95` installed on it without a large number of tabs open, even then the mouse cursor is still responsive and I can close the tab that are causing problems. I would like to hear your suggestions for possible remedies for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Chrome is really heavy on resources. If you open too many tabs on heavy scripted websites (like social medias, web apps, or flash websites) and if you have a lot of chrome extensions running (especially Adblock, unfortunately), your Chrome is prone to crashes.

If you want to know what is using most of your memory or CPU in Chrome, try the Chrome Task Manager (Shift+Esc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but even with 3 tabs open without heavily scripted websites it crashes. The problem is I do not even have the time to bring up the `Chrome Task Manager`. I noticed that the extension EverSync which syncs bookmarks across various browsers uses the most memory, after disabling it I will let you know.

Comment: The problem was related with the **extension** `EverSync` even with two tabs open I noticed it used around 800 MB of RAM, so I disabled it and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out that the culprit was the **extension** `EverSync` it used a tremendous amount of RAM even with two tabs open. After disabling it Google Chrome worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome.

Go to: Menu (The three bars to the right of the address bar) > Settings > Advanced Settings (Bottom of the Settings page) > System > uncheck "Use hardware acceleration where available"

Don't Panic, and don't forget your towel : )